# Is this a good way to call function with parameter in Qt signal and slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QPushButton and when I click the button I will call a method that take two parameters, in this example: `exampleMethod(int i, double d)`.

Now I connect the click event from QPushButton `button` to the exampleMethod like this:
`connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked,this, &Example::exampleMethod);`

But this doesn't work because the parameter of `clicked()` and `exampleMethod(int, double)` are not compatible.

Now I created a extra signal: `exampleSignal(int i, double d)` to connect to my slot:
`connect(this, &Example::exampleSignal, this, &Example::exampleMethod);`

And a additional slot with no parameters: `exampleMethodToCallFromButtonClick()` to call it from QPushButton clicked() in which I call the signal:

```
Example::Example(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent){

    button = new QPushButton("Click", this);

    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked,this, &Example::exampleMethodToCallFromButtonClick);
    connect(this, &Example::exampleSignal, this, &Example::exampleMethod);
}

void Example::exampleMethod(int i, double d){
    qDebug() << "ExampleMethod: " << i << " / " << d;
}

void Example::exampleMethodToCallFromButtonClick(){
    emit exampleSignal(5,3.6);
}
```

This works fine.

1) Now my first question: Is this realy the best way to do this **without lambda**?

With lambda it looks even nicer and I don't need two connect statements:
`connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{exampleMethod(5, 3.6);});`

2) My second question: **with lamba** is this the best way to do this or are there any better ways to solve it?

I also considered to save the parameters from `exampleMethod` as a member variable, call the method without parameter and get instead of the parameters the member variables but I think thats not a so good way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: lambda is a good way.

Comment: In `exampleMethodToCallFromButtonClick()`, no need to use signals to call `exampleMethod`. You can call the fuction directly without relying on SIGNAL/SLOT

Comment: Where do 5 and 3.6 come from? If you get them from some calculation, you can do it in a slot without passing in as parameters

Comment: Thanks, for your answers, your all right. @Jerry the 5 and 3.6 will come from a QTextEdit

Comment: "With lambda it looks even nicer" is not a comment I see every day. :) But seriously, if you're using a button click to emit a signal based on some parameter values, just persist/store/serialize those values, which are presumably editable using some other widgets. Simple enough, yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't do either of those things. Receive the signal, gather your parameters and then just call `exampleMethod`. A lambda is more appropriate when the parameters are known at the point where you connect.

```
Example::Example(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent){

    button = new QPushButton("Click", this);

    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Example::onButtonClicked);
}

void Example::exampleMethod(int i, double d){
    qDebug() << "ExampleMethod: " << i << " / " << d;
}

void Example::onButtonClicked(){
    int i = ...;
    double d = ...;
    exampleMethod(i, d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the single-method approach [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384062/1329652), perhaps the values of `i` and `d` are unrelated and it'd make sense to factor them out to their own methods:

```
int Example::iValue() const {
  ...
}

double Example::dValue() const {
  ...
}
```

Then, the following are equivalent:

```
connect(..., this, [this]{ exampleMethod(iValue(), dValue()); });
connect(..., this, std::bind(&Example::exampleMethod, this, iValue(), dValue()));
```

The choice between `onButtonClicked()` and the use of `iValue()` and `dValue()` is determined mostly by whether the values are useful when factored out separately, and whether for code comprehension it makes sense to specify the call at the `connect` site, or move it out to an individual method.

Finally, if you do use [the single-method approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384062/1329652), and the button is instantiated with `setupUi`, i.e. you've designed `Example` in Designer, you can save the `connect` call by naming the handler method appropriately:

```
Q_SLOT void Example::on_button_clicked();
```

The `button` here is the name of the button object in the .ui file. The connection will be made automatically by `Ui::Example::setupUi(QWidget*)`.